# How do you calculate a confidence interval for a parameter in multiple linear regression?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, least-squares

Suppose $Y = Xβ + ε$, where $Y$ is a random $n$-vector, $X$ is a random $k × n$ matrix, $β$ is a fixed $k$-vector, and $ε$ is a random $n$-vector where the coordinates are independent (of each other and of $X$) and distributed as $N(0, σ^2)$. Given least-squares estimates $\hat β_1,\; \hat β_2,\; …,\; \hat β_k$ of the parameters, how do I compute a $(1 - α)$ confidence interval for one of the parameters $β_i$? Please provide a reference or a proof.

Although this is a pretty fundamental question, I couldn't find a previous CV question that exactly answers it, and poking around textbooks and websites seems to show some disagreement (e.g., should you use the quantile of a normal distribution or a $t$ distribution when multiplying by a standard error?). If there are several reasonable approaches, I'd appreciate a discussion of the differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The covariance matrix of the parameters is the residual variance multiplied by the inverse of the quadratic form of the design matrix. It is a result of the Gauss-Markov theorem (or, specifically, such a variance is a Best Linear Unbiased Estimator: BLUE).

Using matrix notation $\hat{\beta} = (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^TY$.

PROOF: The variance is:

$\text{var}(\hat{\beta}) = (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T var(Y|X) \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}$

$= (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T diag(\sigma^2) \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}$

$= \sigma^2 (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}$

$= \sigma^2 (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}$.

One result which does not require normal residuals: The limiting distribution of the $\hat{\beta}$ is normal.

Thus a 95% CI can be constructed: $\hat{\beta} \pm \mathcal{Z}_{1-\alpha/2} \sqrt{diag(\sigma^2 (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1})}$

Another result when we know residuals are normal but their variance unknown: the estimator is a linear combination of normals and thus is normal. To obtain finite sample inference, the values follow a T-distribution with degrees of freedom equal to the sample size minus the number of free parameters (including the intercept) so that the CI is expressed as:

$\hat{\beta} \pm \mathcal{T}_{1-\alpha/2, n-p} \sqrt{diag(\sigma^2 (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1})}$

Notationally, beta-hat a vector, the SEs also a vector and the $\pm$ a $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} $ operator, basically a sum with an outer product with the [-1, 1] vector.

[Seber Lee, Linear Regression Analysis 2nd ed](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471415405.html)

Comment: Nice. Can you comment on the use of $t$-distributions by, e.g., R's `confint.lm`?

Comment: The result is simpler than you suggest, because since $\hat \beta$ is a linear combination of the responses, it is conditionally Normal already: no limiting argument is needed. One then proceeds as usual to compute the ratio of the estimate to an estimated variance: this will be a suitable multiple of a Student t distribution. Your CI formula could be misinterpreted: it is not a 95% CI for $\hat\beta$.  It's just a collection of *separate* 95% CIs for the various components of $\hat \beta$.  (They are not necessarily conditionally independent.)

Comment: @Kodiologist If 1) the conditional variance is estimated from residuals, 2) the residuals are normally distributed and 3) finite sample inference is desired, then an exact CI can be obtained by using a T-distribution approximation to the sampling distribution of the $\hat{\beta}$ with degrees of freedom equal to the sample size minus the number of free parameters (for instance, with n=100 observations, p=4 covariates, the degrees of freedom would be **5** (with the intercept being the 5th "covariate").

Comment: @whuber I find that in practice, I appeal to this result more frequently. By invoking the Lindeberg-Feller CLT, one does not require the residuals to be normally distributed. My next comment however, addresses your point here.  As far as generating a confidence *interval* versus a confidence ellipse (or hyper ellipse), I admit my notation is a little wonky, but I think it's clear that to generate a CI for the i-th element, one must select the i-th diagonal component from the covariance matrix as the i-th parameter variance.

Comment: I agree with everything in that comment.  The question did stipulate that $\varepsilon$ are normal, though, so it could be helpful to indicate at the outset that you're addressing both a generalization (to non-Normal errors) and a specialization (to large datasets) of the question.

Comment: @whuber great, edited.

Comment: Any idea why I'm failing to replicate `confint.lm` here? https://pastebin.com/qd8Fyqck

Comment: @Kodiologist 1) use DF correction for residual variance `sigma2 <- sum(resid(m)^2)/(length(resid(m)) - length(coef(m)))`. 2) model matrix (X) includes intercept (`X <- cbind(1,x1,x2)`).

Comment: @AdamO Thanks; I'm still getting a slightly different answer (-1.363002  and 4.396348). Is that just numerical error? The difference seems a bit too large for that.

Comment: @Kodiologist https://pastebin.com/KBkCwpUU